# When I use protocol-buffers, how could I know ByteSize() on the server side?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

According to the protocol-buffers api, `ParseFromArray(const void * data, int size)` will fail if the format is wrong, in my case, it return false when the `size` parameter is not right. A lot of answers point out that `ByteSize()` should be used when using `SerializeToArray(void * data, int size)`,and make sure parse the right size, but none of them clearly point out how. So how to pass the `ByteSize()` value to the server side to make sure ParseFromArray doesn't return false?

As far as I know, all the examples I found make the `size` parameter the full size of a receive buffer, and didn't check the return value at all, since the fields will parse any way. Is this a good idea leaving the return value unchecked?

Comment: Protocol buffer format is not self-delimiting. It's up to a higher-level protocol to determine where one protobuf ends and the other begins. It's up to you to define said higher-level protocol.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good idea leaving the return value unchecked?

No!

Where did you get the buffer of data from? Wherever you got it, should have also told you how many bytes are in the buffer.

For example, if you used `recv()` to receive a UDP datagram from the network, it returns the number of bytes received.

If you are using TCP, then again `recv()` returns the number of bytes received, but note that the message may arrive in multiple parts. You need some way to know when it is done, such as by using `shutdown()` to end the stream after the message is sent, or by separately writing the size before the message. For the latter solution, you might be interested in my [pull request](https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/710), which adds helpers to protobufs to accomplish this (but it's not too hard to do yourself, too).

Comment: You enlighten me. I can use the return value of recvfrom().